# Use custom gesture recognizer to trigger scrolling of UIScrollView

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, gesture, gesture-recognition

I cannot find a way to replace the default `UIPanGestureRecognizer` of the`UIScrollView`. However I need to adjust the gesture that causes the `UIScrollView` to scroll.

I only want to recognize pans with higher velocity. In addition, the velocity of a finger is to be measured after it has moved certain distance (to be sure it is not the initial slow motion). To my knowledge this cannot be achieved with `UScrollView`'s default `UIPanGestureRecognizer`.

How can I replace it with my own recognizer?

Comment: Are you using Objective-C or Swift?

Comment: @A.R.Younce I am using Swift. But everything that is possible with with Objective-C should be possible with Swift, right?

Comment: Currently custom subclasses of UIGestureRecognizer can't be written in Swift. I just wanted to know to help come up with example code.

Comment: @A.R.Younce Feel free to write it in Objective-C. I have found a way how to subclass `UIGestureRecogniser`. It has one drawback though with which I can live - so feel free to post in Objective-C I can adapt that code to Swift.

Comment: @A.R.Younce If you are interested how I subclassed `UIGestureRecognizer`: add `import UIKit.UIGestureRecognizerSubclass`

Comment: Excellent. I must have missed that when reading through the docs in the process of building my own for a different use case.

Comment: @A.R.Younce You may still run into some problems - I remember  I did but I do not remember what they were :) If you do try to ask me, I might be able to direct you to the right way.

Answer (score 1):

Changing the underlying gesture recognizer is the wrong way to go. What you want to do can probably be accomplished by implementing the [gestureRecognizer(_:shouldReceiveTouch:)](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Uikit/reference/UIGestureRecognizerDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIGestureRecognizerDelegate/gestureRecognizer:shouldReceiveTouch:) method of [UIGestureRecognizerDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Uikit/reference/UIGestureRecognizerDelegate_Protocol/index.html).

So long as the scroll view you want to customize isn't a part of a UICollectionView, UITableView, or a similar class then you'll be able to set the delegate of the gesture recognizer. Within the delegate you can then use the [velocityInView(_:)](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPanGestureRecognizer_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIPanGestureRecognizer/velocityInView:) method of UIPanGestureRecognizer to decide if you want to allow the gesture recognizer to trigger scrolling.

Comment: Thank you but I must disagree. Currently, I am already using the delegate - not method `shouldReceiveTouch` but rather `gestureRecognizerShouldBegin`. It does not do what's needed. To accomplish what I need by using just the delegate to filter touches may be possible but very complicated. More importantly - it is hacking the `UIPanGestureRecognizer` into recognizing different gesture then pan by means of its delegate. Definitelly not the right way. And the delegate is not meat for it, therefore it does not provide enough controll. Its simply not the same gesture, I need different recognizer.

Comment: Manipulating the gesture recognizers of UIKit framework classes is discouraged for the same reasons as manipulating their private views. Your app may break when they make internal changes. If using the delegate won't work for you then you'll probably need a custom scrolling view (not a UIScrollView subclass).

Comment: Well, if it is not possible to replace default pan recognizer in some documented way, I will need to do much more coding, to recreate whe whole dragging and scrolling functionality - something like you suggest. But before that, I will set up a bounty on this question and see what comes out of it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could implement the touchesMoved method in here as well.  You could do a comparison between touches to check velocity.  something like this but it is pseudo code

```
global firstpoint;
global secondpoint

override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent){

for touch: AnyObject in touches {
        let firstpoint = (touch as UITouch).locationInNode(self);

}
override func touchesMoved(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {

    for touch: AnyObject in touches {
        let secondpoint = (touch as UITouch).locationInNode(self);
    }
    let diffx = secondpoint - firstpoint;
    if diffx > "some value you choose for velocity"{
         "do some action that you want";
    }
    else {
        firstpoint = secondpoint;
    }
}
```

This will give you some velocity for the movement that you could use to supply a further action.

Answer (score 0):

You could try placing a clear UIView over the scrollView, and could then add a UIPanGestureRecognizer to it.  You would then be able to set a selector for that GestureRecognizer that could then tell the scrollView to scroll.  But then you will be responsible for determining the distance to scroll for each high velocity pan.

Comment: I can add `UIPanGestureRecognizer` directly to the `UISrollView` and disable the default one by setting `scrollEnabled = false` (or by implementing `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate`'s method `shouldReceiveTouch` on scroll view and always returning `false`). Determining how far would high velocity pans scroll is also not the problem. The think is I do not want to loose bouncing and paging - and when `contentOffset` or visible rect is set on `UIScrollView` programatically it does not bounce nor it moves to nearest page.